# Connection Refused For Python Selenium Firefox Webdriver When Executed In Jenkins

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, batch-file, jenkins

**TECHNOLOGIES INVOLVED** : Jenkins, python with selenium

**Jenkins Version :** 2.73.2

**Firefox :** 55.0

**REQUIREMENT** : To build a jenkins item, which runs a windows batch file. this bat file inturn triggers a python script. this python script is written with combination of python and selenium for testing.

**Jenkins windows batch command used  :** C:\x\y\z\test.bat

**Bat File Content :** c:\python27\python.exe C:\x\y\z\sample.py %*

**Issue :** Once build now is clicked, its taking too long to build and the py fails in the line "driver = webdriver.Firefox()" and is showing the following error in console output. But Using the same exact command "C:\x\y\z\test.bat" directly in command prompt is executing the bat and triggering the python script and also the python script is running successfully and giving the expected output.

so why is this connection refused exception occurring only when executing via jenkins, even though when the commands are exactly similar ??

Is this correct way to use the same command in both command prompt and Jenkins Build command ?? Please do help in sorting this..

**Console output :**

Line Details     : driver = webdriver.Firefox()

Exception Type   : selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

Exception Detail : Message: connection refused

**Error Stack :**

```
Started by user Admin
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Pythontrigger\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins5312921442058918486.bat

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Pythontrigger\workspace>C:\x\y\z\test.bat

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Pythontrigger\workspace>c:\python27\python.exe C:\x\y\z\sample.py  
Dummy Script
Inside Try
Execution Started
Exception Occured..
Module Name      : C:\x\y\z\sample.py
Line Details     : driver = webdriver.Firefox()
Exception Type   : selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException
Exception Detail : Message: connection refused
```

Process leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information
Finished: SUCCESS

**Code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver

try:
    print 'Dummy Script'
    print 'Inside Try'
    print 'Execution Started'
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    print 'Webdriver done'

except Exception as msg:
    print 'Exception Occured..'
    print msg
```

Comment: You need geckodriver for firefox version 44 and above System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver.driver",
      System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");

Comment: Update the Question with your code trial & the full error stack trace.

Comment: updated the question with the script #Debanjan